# NSCalendar firstWeekday always 1 regardless of user preference

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I am attempting to get the firstWeekday as set in the user's system preferences, using `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]`, however the value returned is always 1 (Sunday) regardless of what is set in the system preferences. Also tried the `autoupdatingCurrentCalendar` with the same results.

From the docs, it states `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` returns a calendar `formed from the settings for the current user’s chosen system locale overlaid with any custom settings the user has specified in System Preferences`. From that description it sounds like I should be able to access the firstWeekday set in the user settings.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is not returning the correct firstWeekday?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal…

Changing the first weekday in `Settings > Calendar > First Weekday` *ONLY* adjusts the day weeks start on in Apple's Calendar app. It does *NOT* adjust underlying `NSCalendar` objects. To do that you'll have to change your phone's region under `Settings > General > Date & Time > Language & Region > Region` to something like Germany to test a calendar with the start of the week as Monday, or US for Sunday, etc.

(To anyone setting out to work on calendar based code: thank you for caring about localization and also here be dragons. Good luck!)